# Selenium Python Checkbox Click

Tags: python, html, selenium, checkbox, click

I am trying to access the following HTML checkbox for a button click:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-value="sf.name" data-ng-model="sf.checked" ng-click="ec.onStateFilterChanged(sf)" title="Select a state" class="ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" value="Arizona">
```

using:

```
state = driver.find_element_by_xpath("input[@type='checkbox']").click()
```

but keep getting error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message:
```

what might be the element path I am looking for in order to select the checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xpath is most likely incorrect - you need to enter `//` before the element as this will find all (single slash `/` will work here too though as you are only trying to find one element and it will find the first match)

Try one of the following:

```py
state = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']").click()
```

OR

```py
state = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='checkbox']").click()
```